# The force a body exert on a floor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Why when a person is standing still on a floor we say that the force that this person acts on the floor equal to it's weight? , Isn't the weight the force that the earth pulls the person and acts only on the person, how then this force goes to the ground ?

Answer (score 1):

It is, indeed, an indirect result.

First, apply Newton's second law on the person at rest. Two forces are present, weight and the reaction applied by the floor. Projecting this on the vertical direction yields:
$$P+R=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad R=-P$$

Second, apply Newton's third law: the reaction that the person applies on the floor is the opposite of the reaction that the floor applies on the person. So the former is equals to $P$.

This means that if the person isn't at rest (for example they're falling to the floor), this result becomes invalid.